# Cilk Plus code result depends on number of workers

Tags: c++, multithreading, cilk-plus

I have a small piece of code that I would like to parallelize as I upscale. I've been using `cilk_for` from Cilk Plus to run the multithreading. The trouble is that I get a different result depending on the number of workers.

I've read that this might be due to a race condition, but I'm not sure what specifically about the code causes that or how to ameliorate it. Also, I realize that `long` and `__float128` are overkill for this problem, but might be necessary in the upscaling.

Code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "cilk/cilk.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

__float128 direct(const vector<double>& Rpct, const vector<unsigned>& values,     double Rbase, double toWin) {
    unsigned count = Rpct.size();
    __float128 sumProb = 0.0;
    __float128 rProb = 0.0;
    long nCombo = static_cast<long>(pow(2, count));

//  for (long j = 0; j < nCombo; ++j) { //over every combination
    cilk_for (long j = 0; j < nCombo; ++j) { //over every combination
        vector<unsigned> binary;

        __float128 prob = 1.0;
        unsigned point = Rbase;
        
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++i) { //over all the individual events
            long exp = static_cast<long>(pow(2, count-i-1));
            bool odd = (j/exp) %  2;  
            if (odd) {
                binary.push_back(1);
                point += values[i];
                prob *= static_cast<__float128>(Rpct[i]); 
            } else {
                binary.push_back(0);
                prob *= static_cast<__float128>(1.0 - Rpct[i]);  
            }            
        }

        sumProb += prob;
        if (point >= toWin)         rProb += prob;
        assert(sumProb >= rProb);
    }

    //print sumProb
    cout << " sumProb = " << (double)sumProb << endl;
    assert( fabs(1.0 - sumProb) < 0.01);

    return rProb;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<double> Rpct;
    vector<unsigned> value;

    value.assign(20,1);
    Rpct.assign(20,0.25);

    unsigned Rbase  = 22;
    unsigned win = 30;

    __float128 rProb = direct(Rpct, value, Rbase, win);

    cout << (double)rProb << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output for `export CILK_NWORKERS=1 &&  ./code.exe`:

> sumProb = 1
>
> 0.101812

Sample output for `export CILK_NWORKERS=4 &&  ./code.exe`:

> sumProb = 0.948159
>
> Assertion failed: (fabs(1.0 - sumProb) < 0.01), function direct, file code.c, line 61.
>
> Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of a race condition. cilk_for is implementation of parallel for algorithm. If you want to use parallel for you must use independent iteration (independent data). It`is very important. You have to use cilk reducers for your case: https://www.cilkplus.org/tutorial-cilk-plus-reducers

Comment: Defining `sumProb` and `rProb` as `cilk::reducer< cilk::op_add<double> >` did the trick. I understand that it's the simultaneous access, editing, and saving of these variables that could lead to erroneous results. I'd imagine that if I instead saved them to a vector, and then summed the vector outside the for-loop would work too.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, there is at least one race on sumProb. Each of the parallel workers will do a read/modify/write on that location. As sribin mentioned above, solving problems like this is what reducers are for.

It's entirely possible that there's more than one race in your program. The only way to be sure is to run it under a race detector, since finding races is one of the things that computers are **much** better at than humans. A free possibility is the Cilkscreen race detector, available from the [cilkplus.org](https://www.cilkplus.org/download#block-views-cilk-tools-block-1) website. Unfortunately it doesn't support gcc/g++.